# gpg key timed out error while installing GNU Octave on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, ppa, repository, octave

I tried to install Octave using the following commands:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:octave/stable`
2. `sudo apt update`
3. `sudo apt-get install octave`

But after running the 1st command, I get the following error:

```
The latest version of GNU Octave built for all supported Ubuntu releases. GNU Octave is normally distributed with Ubuntu, this PPA is for you if you have a need to use a newer version of Octave than what you can already get from your installed version of Ubuntu.

Simply follow the instructions below to add this PPA to your system and install the octave package. If it's not that easy or you encounter any errors, contact the team and let us know.

Much credit goes to the Debian Octave Group who maintain the official Debian packages that this work is derived from. Without their efforts to bring Octave packaging to such a high level of quality in Debian and Debian derivatives, this PPA would not be here.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~octave/+archive/ubuntu/stable
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Error: retrieving gpg key timed out.
```

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Retrieving GPG keys from the SKS keyserver network is facing problems (I guess?). You'll have to retrieve the GPG key for the repo from elsewhere. (I may be wrong)

Comment: Suppose your guess is right, how do I retrieve the GPG key?

Comment: Make sure you have an Internet connection and try this:
`sudo gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv F265CD39647D184843E5F27D4F2D377DDCB1CB6E`.

Then, try adding the PPA again.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. The ppa for the Octave is in old version, so, I directly tried running the 3rd step : `sudo apt install octave` and it worked fine. By the way, thanks for the help @ Mukesh Sai Kumar

Comment: Anytime :) You can answer your own question here to help others find a solution if they face the same problem as yours

Answer (score 2):

At almost all the places over the internet the above 3 steps are recommended to install Octave.

But [the PPA of this software](https://launchpad.net/~octave/+archive/ubuntu/stable?field.series_filter=) is for older versions of Ubuntu (16.04 LTS and 14.04 LTS). And doesn't need to be added explicitly.

Directly, run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install octave
```

It should work fine. Hope this helps :)